# Escape HTML and Javascript tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a editable textbox. If I will enter alert('Hi'); , then it saves properly. After saving it will forward to a list page where that text box value will be a hyperlink.
If we click on that hyperlink then alert displays.
But we want to escape this.
Can any one have the resolution for this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and find its `encodeRFC5987ValueChars` example.

Comment: Lets say I have a text box. <input type="text" name="studentName"> . When I will enter some text "  <script> alert('Hi');</script>  " . then it behaves like a javascript. Hence it alert comes up onload of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the text is saved for further processing or display,
replace all `"<"` by `"&lt;"`
and replace all `">"` by `"&gt;"`